# WIX: Unable to perform Major Upgrade using Orca at run time

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, orca

I am using WIX to create a MSI file . The Problem is even if I change its Package code and Product code without changing upgrade code using ORCA , it is not doing Major Upgrade previous version , rather it creates an new independent instance. But when I create new MSI with same upgrade code it successfully upgrades previous instance rather than creating new one.

Below are my product.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
   <Product Id="*" Name="PranaNirvana" Language="1033" Version="1.7.1.35" Manufacturer="Nirvana Solutions" UpgradeCode="5f546b4e-65b3-42d3-b4f3-f7153319dedc">
      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
      <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
```

**Is there any other parameter to change in order to create a Major Upgrade?**

Comment: Do you increment version number? (not that 4-th digit is ignored, only first 3 digits are significant)